# Correct way to use XmlSerialization with frequent serializations

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, file-io, xml-serialization

I have a list box that when an item is selected or deselected I want to save the changes to an xml file (so it is always up-to-date on the file and the user does not need a "save" button).

While testing I occasionally am hitting this IOException:

**The process cannot access the file 'C:\MyPath\MyFile.xml' because it is being used by another process.**

Here is my XML Serialization code:

```
// Save an object out to the disk
public static void SerializeObject<T>(this T toSerialize, String filename)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(toSerialize.GetType());
    TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(filename);

    xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, toSerialize);
}

// Load an object from the disk
private static T DeserialzeObject<T>(String filename) where T : class
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    try
    {
        TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(filename);
        return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(textReader);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    { }

    return null;
}
```

And here is how it is called:

```
// Save off the list because the visibility has changed
public void WorkItemColumnTypeOnVisibleChanged(int fieldID, Visibility visibility)
{
    ColumnFields.SerializeObject(ColumnFields.GetSerializeFilename());
}
```

The deserialize is the one that is giving the error:

```
WorkItemColumnTypes savedVersion = DeserialzeObject<WorkItemColumnTypes>(result.GetSerializeFilename());
```

Is there a way to optimize my connections to the file so that I am not tripping over myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you need to call `Close` on the `TextWriter` objects in your serialization and deserialization methods? Or alternatively use the `using` construct to force disposal at the end of the block.

Example:

```
// Save an object out to the disk
public static void SerializeObject<T>(this T toSerialize, String filename)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(toSerialize.GetType());
    using(TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(filename))
    {

        xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, toSerialize);
    }
}

// Load an object from the disk
private static T DeserialzeObject<T>(String filename) where T : class
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    try
    {
        using(TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(filename))
        {
            return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(textReader);
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    { }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: The call to close fixed it.  Thanks!

Comment: The using way is safer in case the serialization or deserialization itself raises an exception. You could handle that by putting the close in a finally clause, but that's exactly what using does for you.